# Get mime type of external file using cURL and php

Tags: php, curl, mime-types

I've used `mime_content_type()` and File info but i never successed. i want to use now cURL with PHP and get the headers of the file which is hosted on another domain then extract & determine if the type is MP3 or not. ( i think the mime type of MP3 is `audio/mpeg` )

Briefly, i know that but i don't know how to apply it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### PHP curl_getinfo()

```
<?php
  # the request
  $ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_exec($ch);

  # get the content type
  echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

  # output
  text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
?>
```

### curl

`curl -I http://www.google.com`

### output

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 09 Apr 2010 20:35:12 GMT
Expires: Sun, 09 May 2010 20:35:12 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
```

Comment: Just to warn others: If you are downloading external files to your server, the mime type the opposing server provides might be deliberately altered. Do not trust the Content Type. Instead, download the file and use the local tools PHP provides.

Answer (score 22):

You can use a HEAD request via curl. Like:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$results = explode("\n", trim(curl_exec($ch)));
foreach($results as $line) {
    if (strtolower(strtok($line, ':')) == 'content-type') {
        $parts = explode(":", $line);
        echo trim($parts[1]);
    }
}
```

Which returns: **image/png**

Comment: thats great! it will only get the headers and saves a lot of time and resources for big images. If you are using it now - change split function to explode (as it has been deprecated from php5.3)

Comment: Can't you extract the `Content-Type:` header directly from curl and skip the rest? Like `curl --write-out '%{content_type}' --silent $URL`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok with a more elegant Zend Framework version, [here is a class](http://smartycode.com/rapidphp/getting-mime-of-remote-file-with-zend-framework/) which makes use of Zend_Http_Client component.

Use it like so:

```
$sniffer = new Smartycode_Http_Mime(); 
$contentType = $sniffer->getMime($url);
```