# Safely upload/download images via URL

Tags: php, image, download

So, I want to safely download images from a URL. My first thought, of course, is to check the extension - if it's compatible, just download it and save it with the good extension (it should be safe because the server won't run PHP code stored in a `.jpg` file (well, unless it's configured to do so)). Is there still some risk using this method, and if there is better way to do it?

Comment: When you say "safely", what is your concern?

Comment: I'm concerned that a user could download an executable file or image with an exploit to gain control of the server.

Comment: Is that a legitimate concern?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

to get file info you can use `curl_getinfo()`
more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610713/get-mime-type-of-external-file-using-curl-and-php)

This should help you download anything via url with php. 
And about upload? you want to save file somewhere or what?

Comment: I dont think you understand. I've already used file_get_contents (well i could use curl but didn't seem any diference at the time so just to get along with it and test..). Downloading data from url is not the problem. Problem is to do it safe - i mean i want this to be used only with images so i did parse link for extension and i save it with same extension (only image-ext are allowed) but is it enough safe or should i check something else too?

And by safe i mean of coure that i don't want someone to hack it and upload php shell or something else that could be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if it's an image, because the extension can be manipulated.

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);
if(@imagecreatefromstring($file)) { 
  // it's a valid image file; handle it
}
else {
  // it's not an image file; error!
}
```