# Check if a remote file is a valid mp3

Tags: php, mime-types

Could you tell me a good way to check if a remote(http) file is a valid mp3, WITHOUT downloading the whole file?

Comment: What is a "valid mp3"? You could check the headers (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610713/get-mime-type-of-external-file-using-curl-and-php), but that doesn't guarantee the file will play. You'd have to download the whole file to be sure of that.

Comment: How does the MP3 need to be validated? Entirely? Just the what the remote server thinks it is (MIME type)? Just if it has a valid ID3 header?

Comment: A 'valid' mp3 can be 100gigabytes of random garbage, with a single mp3 frame buried in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Do not trust anything that comes from the server. MIME type may be fake. Even the filename. Just assume that you are expecting a MP3 file. Store the correct extension and verify it.

Well at least the header along with the correct extension to the filename. At worst they get a horrible noise in their ears and you get a complaint.

Comment: The thing is that I made a database with links of mp3 sounds from remote servers, and I'm making a script wich is fetching all the links and checks if they are still "online", and if they are deleted to not go to some remote hosting sites.. But if I download all the mp3 sounds and check them daily I ill make HUGE traffic...

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://...music.mp3");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$header = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
curl_close($curl);

$mp3_mimes = array('audio/mpeg','application/mp3','audio/mpeg3','audio/x-mpeg-3');
if (in_array($info, $mp3_mimes)) {
    // Somthign cooking
}
```

Another suggestion is download the file and validated by reading header information

```
$curl = curl_init();

$localfile = "local.temp";
unlink($localfile);

$file = fopen($localfile, 'w+');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://robtowns.com/music/blind_willie.mp3"); // nput
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);

$mp3 = new mp3();
if ($info = $mp3->get_mp3($localfile, true, false)) {
    var_dump($info);
} else {
    unlink($localfile);
    // bad File
}
```

[MP3Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5275-PHP-Manipulate-MP3-audio-files.html)

Comment: Not sure this is the right approach.  First, you're only checking the content type as the server sent it, but I can easily send you a file with content type "audio/mpeg" and total rubbish inside.  Second, `audio/mpeg` is not only mp3, but also mp2, which uses different encoding.

Comment: Sometimes servers send `"Content-Type: application/mp3"`.

Comment: @NullUserException you are right .. i would work on that too thanks

Comment: @NullUserException or sometimes even `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: The thing is that I made a database with links of mp3 sounds from remote servers, and I'm making a script wich is fetching all the links and checks if they are still "online", and if they are deleted to not go to some remote hosting sites.. But if I download all the mp3 sounds and check them daily I ill make HUGE traffic...

Comment: @Марин-Мемо Митрев since you don't need the files you can just check the headers .... as demonstrated above but some will show `application/octet-stream` as  Aleks G mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Check the filesize and if its >1mb validate... Not the answer but the best for now...