# PHP distinguish between image url and url of page with that image

Tags: php, image, dom

I have a script that can find images from a URL, given by the user.

So for input string: "http://www.google.com/",
I use something like

```
$html = file_get_html ( $url );
if ($html->find ( 'img' )) {....}
```

It brings the result as 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'.

But  if the user inputs a string "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png". There is no img tag. URL is valid, but code fails. How can this case be included in the code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: So you're asking how to find out whether a URL points to an image?

Comment: @SLaks Now that you said so, I think you are right. That was the right question to ask. And I guess I can find the answer readily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to [perform a HEAD request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-head.php) and check the content type to see if the URL corresponds to an image. If it's an image, then do whatever you want with it, but if it's an HTML page, then use your other code.

Comment: This would be much more efficient than my answer.

Comment: @Micah Thanks I am gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to get the content type from the server. Then if its an image mime type you can use it directly instead of parsing the html.

[Get mime type of external file using cURL and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610713/get-mime-type-of-external-file-using-curl-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the images, I would use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the content of the page, and then use [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) to turn it into a gd image resource. This returns false if it can't turn it into an image, so you can then use str_get_html to parse the html (assuming you're using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)