# how can i check if a given URL is an image?

Tags: php, image

I thought of using `getimagesize($url);` but there are still many cases where i can access the image through the browser but the same image returns nothing from `getimagesize($url);`

```
$url = 'http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/model/2012/P01 06826 05102 04 0026 4.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[]&set=key[width],value[]&set=key[height],value[]&set=key[x],value[]&set=key[y],value[]&set=key[type],value[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/large] ';
```

Comment: do you want to know if the url is an image or are you actually looking for an alternative to `getimagesize()`?

Comment: i am trying to find out if a url is an image yes. and getimagesize seemed like a good idea but for some reason still return empty array for urls i am 100% sure working

Comment: Alternative for what? As long as you don't say why `getimagesize` is not able to do the job, it's hard to say which alternative might do it. Also please search the site, we have *many* alternatives listed for dealing with remote images and obtaining their size and type,

Comment: You find out about errors and warnings when you start to handle them, e.g. enable the highest reporting level, log errors and then follow the error log. http://www.phptherightway.com/#error_reporting

Comment: I have absolutely no clue why it doesn't work for certain images

Comment: There can be thousand reasons: Redirects, Cookies (or other request headers that are required but not set), Timeouts and what not. You need to troubleshoot what you actually need here. Maybe doing some little search and scanning the first 50-100 results gives you a pretty good impression: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+getimagesize+URL  -- Imagine if you can't say what the problem is, how should we be able to answer it?

Comment: And the classic: What is `$url` when it does not work? Please add the output of `var_dump($url);`to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just check the Content-Type header for the string `image`.

Just use the function `get_headers()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

You can also use curl if it's available on your system, details here: [Get mime type of external file using cURL and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610713/get-mime-type-of-external-file-using-curl-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

To use getimagesize() you need to download the url and save it as a local file.  Then pass the string of the filename stored locally to getimagesize().