# How can I tell if a URL points to an image?

Tags: php

I have a php page with a text input where the user is supposed to paste a remote URL of an image, and I will have to store it in the server and display it to the user. Now the problem is, I don't trust a user will always provide a proper image url, and I don't want them to upload a pdf or other file, or a huge, few gb worth of file. Now I can check the extension, but that isn't very helpful, and I hear I can check the mime-type, but I don't know how I can open the file once and check all the validations like mime-type and file size in one go, and then copy the file over. Moreover, since the file will be pretty much served as it is(with a minor name change), I would like to know if it is possible to make sure that the file doesn't have any injected virus or problematic code.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: this could help you determining mime type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610713/get-mime-type-of-external-file-using-curl-and-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are really multiple things that can be done here.  I would suggest using cURL as your mechanism for transferring the file (rather than `file_get_contents()` or similar).  The reason for this is that you can first send a HEAD request against the resource to just get the header information before committing to actually download it.  From the headers, you should be able to evaluate the file name, file size, mime-type information, etc.  Note that NONE of this information should be trusted, but it at least gives you a sanity check before committing to the file download.

Once you have done the sanity check, you can download the file into a local snadbox directory.  This should not be a web-accessible directory.  You could use `exif_imagetype()` to determine if the file is indeed an image of the type you are interested in.

Assuming this all looks good, I would just do the last bit of cleanup-and renaming in GD library (perhaps use `imagecreatefrom*()` functions to make final image from the temp download file).

Comment: If I store it to server first, and then try to reopen and work with it...would it be 100% safe? I guess I am just putting the content in memory, but still I want to be sure that no malware code can be executed on the server. Also to make the tmp_image folder inaccessible to web, what method would you recommend? htaccess?

Comment: @aoi Just put the file in a directory like `/tmp` for Linux that is accessible by the web server but not in underneath the web root. The file could certainly contain malware, but you are not trying to execute it, rather you are just investigating it's binary structure.  Honestly, image-based exploits are fairly rare and I think taking the precaution to actually look at the image signature and then copying it in GD would be sufficient mitigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exif_imagetype()` to see if its an image.

If you want to be 100% sure that its not malware or something weird. its a good idea to use the GD library and save it via the GD library. So there is no `dangerous` code inside.

Comment: If I open it via gd library after storing to server(a tmp file) and then re-save it, will there be any chance of any serverside malware code being executed? I am asking this cause rather than opening a remote url multiple times, i would rather store a local copy to server and perform the validations on it.

Comment: Its a real small change, ofcourse you need to check if its an image first. Extention check, file size, has it a width, height ect. You can even save the temp file as an base64() hash to be real sure.

Answer (score 0):

With Curl you have no problem with https, you may store a file and check it.
Here is the code to check content-type for image then file is checked with exif_imagetype() (enable php_mbstring and php_exif extentions).

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/images/icons/ui/doodle_plus/doodle_plus_google_logo_on_grey.gif';

$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';       
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_exec( $ch ) ;
if(!curl_errno($ch))  
{
    $type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE); 
    if ( stripos($type, 'image') !== FALSE )
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);    
        $filename = tempnam('/path/to/store/file/', 'prefix');
        $fp=fopen($filename,'wb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
        curl_exec($ch);
        fclose($fp);
        if ( exif_imagetype($filename) !== FALSE )
        {
            echo "100% IMAGE!";
            // take it!
        }

        unlink($filename);
    }      
}

curl_close($ch);
```