# Get image type from mime type in PHP

Tags: php, image, mime-types, file-extension

In PHP, there are two functions, **[image_type_to_extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-extension.php)** and **[image_type_to_mime_type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php)**, however, I am looking for the oppsite. Is there something like **mime_type_to_image_type** so I can retrieve the type from the mime (I only have image/jpeg, or image/png, and like to eventually get the extension)?

Please note that I cannot use **exif_imagetype** or **getimagesize** because the hosting server does not allow it. The php setting **allow_url_fopen** is turned off for security reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for a built-in PHP function to convert from mime type (eg: image/jpeg) to IMAGETYPE_XXX (eg: IMAGETYPE_JPEG). Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use the [Client URL Library (cURL)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to extract this information from the raw data of the file. You can see some examples [in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610713/get-mime-type-of-external-file-using-curl-and-php).

Comment: I looked into this answer already. Too complicated for what I like to do. All I want is the opposite of the above two functions. What if I do not have an image, but I only have the type above? Then the cURL answer would not work. Therefore I asked my question. Thanks.