# Determining file type in PHP without MIME or extension

Tags: php

I have a PHP website that takes file uploads, and I want to be able to do certain actions based on the file type. But I don't want to trust what type of file the browser says it is, and would rather read the file's header to determine it. Do any libraries exist for this in PHP? Or would this be something I need to write from scratch?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `finfo` functions which do this for you.

Where previously you could use the mime_content_type function, this has now been deprecated, so, instead, use

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$type  = $finfo->file('path/filename');
```

Comment: I'm unsure why this is downvoted. While, yes, it uses MIME - it is not using the MIME type reported by the browser.

Comment: Is it using the file name to determine the MIME? Or is it reading the file header?

Comment: I imagine it uses mime.magic

Comment: A better approach: $type = finfo_open($path_to_image);

Comment: @directedition It does no use file name to determine the MIME. Even if the file extension on the file is incorrect, this reports the correct type of file regardless of what extension it has.

mime_content_type ( $path_to_file ) also works.

Answer (score 3):

file info function can give you file type

```
 $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

 echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
```

it can give output like

```
text/html
image/gif
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in PHP called `fread()` that you can use to read in a binary file:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

You could use this to read in the first few bytes of the file to get the header and determine the file type that way.

Comment: That's far from a complete way to determine a file's type.

Comment: No s*** Sherlock - obviously he's gonna have to analyze the contents of whatever he's read from the file to determine the file type. Read his question again: "...would rather read the file's header to determine it. Do any libraries exist for this in PHP? Or would this be something I need to write from scratch?"

Comment: I read his question.  There are several ways to do this without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

curl_getinfo should help http://php.net/curl_getinfo
related to this question: [Get mime type of external file using cURL and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610713/get-mime-type-of-external-file-using-curl-and-php)