# PHP-How to check webpage(url) contain video or not?

Tags: php

I create website for RSS reader.
I want to add new feature in it.
For this I want to test that webpage(url)
contain video or not??
Can any one tell me that how to do this??
I just want to test that the url or webpage contain video or not??

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2610713/362536

Comment: @Brad how this is duplicate??

Comment: How is it not a duplicate?  You asked how to check if a URL is a video.  To do that, you need to examine the `Content-Type` response header to see if it is of a video type.

Comment: He asked how to test if a page contains a video, not is a video.

Comment: That's not an appropriate comment, he may have misread the question or not understood the difference. I've done so before.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is to scan the source code of the page through PHP and look for likely embedded video codes. Those can vary though, so you may need to look for several patterns. Some video sharing sites embed them via iframes though, and that will be harder to deal with.

There are plenty of examples on the web on how to parse a site's generated source code, but be careful of violating their terms of use.