# How to get the image extention from function file_get_content()

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a url something like this

```
$url ="www.domain.com/image.php?id=123&idlocation=987&number=01";
```

Previously i was getting the extension using following code

```
$img_details= pathinfo($url);
```

But this won't work any more since the url has other variables also . So in this case how to get the Image name and extension .

I know i should first download the file using

```
$contenido = file_get_contents($url);
```

But don't know how to get the files name/extention  from this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/image.php?id=123&idlocation=987&number=01';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$results = split("\n", trim(curl_exec($ch)));
foreach($results as $line) {
        if (strtok($line, ':') == 'Content-Type') {
                $parts = explode(":", $line);
                echo trim($parts[1]);
        }
}
```

Return: image/png

Already answered in: [Get mime type of external file using cURL and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610713/get-mime-type-of-external-file-using-curl-and-php)

Comment: Is there any other way than using curl ?, Like with using get_file_content() and then some other function on the downloaded variable to get the extension

Comment: This will work in most cases but you still depend on the server returning the correct content-type header and not something like application/octet-stream. If the image is already downloaded it might be easier to check the first few bytes - for examle JPEG always starts with 0xFF 0xD8, GIF starts with GIF etc.

Comment: You might try parsing the $http_response_header variable after file_get_contents(). It will be the same as parsing the headers from cURL . I admit I have never used this method since cURL gives more flexibility but according to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php it should work

Answer (score 0):

The above answers focus both on the mime-type and they will work in most cases they both need additional resource usage - either a second network call to get the mime type or more disk reads/writes to save the file to disk and use the exif-imagetype function. And both will not return the file name which was a part of the question. Here is a download function using curl that will return a downloaded file as an array with name,mime type and content. Additionally it will try to get the name from the URL if possible.

Sample usage

```
$file=downloadfile($url);
echo "Name: ".$file["name"]."<br>";
echo "Type: ".$file["mimetype"]."<br>";
```

Code

```
function downloadfile($url){
  global $headers;

  $headers=array();
  $file=array("content"=>"","mimetype"=>"","name"=>"");

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'readHeaders');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $file["content"]=curl_exec($ch);
  if(sizeof($headers)){
    foreach($headers as $header){
      if(!strncasecmp($header,'content-type:',13)){
        $file["mimetype"]=trim(substr($header,13));
      }
      elseif(!strncasecmp($header,'content-disposition:',20)){
        $file["name"]=trim(substr(strstr($header,'filename='),9));
      }
    }
  }
  if(!$file["name"]){
    $query=strpos("?",$url);
    $file["name"]=basename(substr($url,0,($query?$query:strlen($url))));
  }
  unset($headers);
  return $file;
}
function readHeaders($ch, $header) {
  global $headers;
  array_push($headers, $header);
  return strlen($header);
}
```